# Serverless - large app

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-architecture

I am new to serverless framework.

I am starting a Rest API that will have multiple routing, for example:

GET user/{userid}

POST user

---

GET account/{accountid}

POST account

Do I need 2 services - account + users?

What are the best practices? If 2 services then 2 serverless.yml? does any one have example for serverless large app?

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

For your example it's enough to use one service (serverless.yml).

You can use one lambda in 1 service to handle `users` and `accounts` requests.

```
functions:
  <your-function-name>:
    handler: handler.execute
    events:
      - http:
          path: /user/{userid}
          method: get
      - http:
          method: post
          path: /user    
      - http:
          path: /account/{accountid}
          method: get
      - http:
          method: post
          path: /account
```

Or you can create 2 lambdas (one per entity)

```
functions:
  user:
    handler: userHandler.execute
    events:
      - http:
        path: /user/{userid}
        method: get
      - http:
        method: post
        path: /user
  account:
    handler: accountHandler.execute
    events:
      - http:
        path: /account/{accountid}
        method: get
      - http:
          method: post
          path: /account
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the architecture you want for your app.
Take a look [here](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-architecture-code-patterns/), I think it might help you decide what you want really want.

If you have a lot of endpoints at one point you might need 2 services, because you'll reach the resources limit. You can always set the `pathmapping` if you want to have one single url for your app.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    pathmapping:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
      Properties:
        BasePath: <your base for this service>
        DomainName: mydomain.com
        RestApiId:
            Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        Stage: dev
```

Answer (score 1):

In few words - as you wish.
Technically: you can aggregate several functions into one, and invoke specific one, base on event parameter attribute. Moreover - you can run express/koa server inside AWS lambdas (or other FaaS) without any pain.
+ as a bonus you can use `ANY` and `{any+}`:

```
    events:
  - http:
      path: /foo
      method: ANY
  - http:
      path: /foo/{any+}
      method: ANY
```

But in general - depends on situation. If you invoke specific endpoint very often, then it's better to move it to separated lambda. If you know that bench of endpoints invoked seldom - it's better to aggregate them under one lambda. Especially if you use warm-up.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I like about architecture is that there is no right answer, but the most suitable for your problem/situation. On top of that, best/good practices are a guideline to help you on all of that.

In my case, I added the complexity to the code so my CRUD paths are very simple.
cms/{entity} or cms/{entity}/{id}. Entity means my collection in my BackEnd, so I know which model to use.

Applying this to your question you would have something like:

```
GET {entity}/{userid}
POST {entity}
```

With this solution you don't have to create a function for each new entity you create in your DB. It also has the Open-Closed concept of the SOLID principles.